# Intern: Testing async unit tests with ES6 promises

Tags: intern

I have some async functions that I need to test via Intern. Each uses ES6 promises.

In the Intern docs, it says that test functions that return a promise pass as soon as that promise is resolved. However, I not only care about whether the async function I am testing is resolved/rejected, I also want to check to make sure the resolved value is correct.

Example: I have my function:

```javascript
function getSomething() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do some async stuff and resolve when done
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('the value');    
    }, 1000);

  });
}
```

Then I have the test method:

```javascript
tdd.test('getSomething', function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getSomething().then(function(value) {
      // I want to resolve/reject the promise BASED ON the assertion -- if the assertion fails, I want to reject the promise; if it succeeds, I want to resolve it
      assert.equal(value, 'the value', 'getSomething should return "the value".');
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

I've noticed this doesn't work -- if the assertion fails in my test, the resolve() never gets called.

How would I be able to resolve/reject the promise conditioned upon the assertion? Should I wrap the assertion in a try/catch? I didn't see any documentation on the Intern docs about this (and most were using this.async() instead of ES6 promises).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening in your code is that the assertion in the `getSomething` callback is throwing an exception, and that's preventing `resolve` from being called. The `getSomething` promise will be rejected, but since you're not returning it in the wrapper promise's initializer, the wrapper promise is never resolved or rejected.

There is no need to wrap the promise returned by `getSomething` in a new promise. Just return it directly.

Comment: So the test would just be ```return getSomething.then(function(){ assert('whatever') })```? Will the assert be called, since in that case the promise has already been resolved by that point?

Comment: Yes (`getSomething().then` -- don't forget the parens). The assert will be called after the `getSomething()` promise resolves. That's fine, because the thing you're returning is actually a promise chain, and that chain won't resolve until the `then` callback (and hence the assertion) executes. (It could also reject if the `getSomething` promise rejects, but that's also fine.)